# In Rails, how do you swap a new object for an existing one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have the following nested model relationship:

- Countries (id, name)

  - Provinces (id, country_id, name)

    - Cities (id, province_id, name)

I have `validates_uniqueness_of` constraint on the name fields for each model in the relationship and a unique index on the name columns in the database.

I want to swap a new object created with the same name as an existing record at some point before it's validated. In other words, if a user attempts to add a city, province, country combination that has already been added, I want to country model to return a reference to the corresponding existing model records instead of failing validation before save.

I'm having trouble using the model callbacks (`after_initialize`, `before_validation`, etc.) and I wasn't able to get `Country.find_or_initialize_by_name` to work with the nested models... any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us some more information on the troubles you are having? Are errors being thrown? If so, what do they say? The more information you give us the easier it will be to help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do sounds pretty hard and will probably require you to know a lot of the internal implementation details of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Instead, could you do something like this?

```
@country = Country.find_or_initialize_by_name(params[:name])
...
@country.save
```

**EDIT:**
ActiveRecord has `find_or_create_by_XXX` and `find_or_initialize_by_XXX` functions built in, so there is no need to add a function to the model.  For more info see the "Dynamic attribute-based finders" section of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: I'd probably get stuck with the same issue I have using `find_or_initialize_by_name`: The nested models do not use this method, so it will work fine on a Country, but the province will throw a validation error because internally it does not call `find_or_initialize_by_name`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want your Province model to do.  What code do want to run and how do you want it to behave?  If it were me, I would simply find/create the Country, then pass the country ID to whatever function you use to create the Province; then there is no need for provinces to automatically create countries.  But you should be able to get that working if you really wanted to.

Comment: I knew about the `find_or_initialize` method, I listed it as a failed attempt in my question (at least as per my attempt). The nested relationship is the other way around; a country is created and accepts nested attributes for provinces. In turn, a province accepts nested attributes for cities.